# How to remove/disable the cmd+k shortcut to open search in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

Hello community I am trying to remove/disable the cmd+k shortcut that opens the search part of the url bar in firefox.
I usually just use cmd+l to focus the url bar and just search from there. The cmd+k sometimes interferes with command palettes of websites.

I have looked through a lot of docs and here a couple website talking about disable other keys but it seems much more complicated that I thought it should be.

[https://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20220329-firefox-disable-ctrl-w.html](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Egautam/sj/blog/20220329-firefox-disable-ctrl-w.html)

https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/948441

Any help would be great!